# Documents similar to Microsoft's guide on creating the best user experience

Tags: guidelines, design-principles

For several years, I've refered back to Microsoft's [best user experience guide document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468595.aspx) but I'm starting to think that by just using one guide as my, uh, guide, I may be narrowing my horizons a little.

Are there any other decently written guides out there that are in the same vein, that are worth reading, or that you hold dear?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/)

Comment: thats brilliant - I didn't even think to check apple, despite them creating some very elegent interfaces! doh me

Comment: Here's a list of HIGs on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_guidelines#Examples_of_HIG

Answer (score 17):

**Apple**

[iPhone & iPad (iOS) User Experience Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Principles/Principles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW1)

[iPhone & iPad (iOS) User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Principles/Principles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH5-SW1)

[Mac OS X User Experience Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/UEGuidelines/UEGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002720-TPXREF101)

[Mac OS X User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Menus/Menus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000356-TP6)

**Google**

[Android User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)

[Design Principles](http://www.google.com/about/corporate/company/ux.html#useful)

[Google TV Web Site Optimization Resources](http://code.google.com/tv/web/)

[Website Design & Content Guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#1)

**BlackBerry**

[Blackberry Browser Content Design Guidelines (PDF)](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/4305/BlackBerry_Browser-4.6.0-US.pdf)

[User Interface Guidelines for Blackberry Playbook Tablet](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/27299/index.jsp?name=UI%20Guidelines%20-%20BlackBerry%20PlayBook%20TabletBlackBerry%20PlayBook%20Tablet1.0&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Development%20Guidelines&subCategory=)

[User Interface Guidelines for Blackberry Smartphones](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/28627/index.jsp?name=UI%20Guidelines%20-%20BlackBerry%20SmartphonesBlackBerry%20Smartphones7.0%20Beta&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Development%20Guidelines&subCategory=)

**Microsoft**

[Microsoft Surface User Experience Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19410)

[Windows Mobile User Interface Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158602.aspx)

[Windows Touch User Interface Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872774.aspx)

[Windows User Experience & User Interface Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511440.aspx)

**IBM**

[Design Principles](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/ucd/designconcepts/designbasics.html)

[User experience guidelines for IBM Lotus rich client applications and plug-ins](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/d-ls-ueguidelines/)

**Adobe**

[Adobe Flex UI Design and RIA Workflow](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/design.html)

**HP**

[User Interface Guidelines for Palm webOS](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/design/mojo/user-interface-summary.html)

[Enyo Design Guidelines](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/design/design-enyo.html)

**Motorola**

[Motorola Best Practices for Android User Interface](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Best_Practices_for_User_Interfaces/)

**Nokia**

[Design & User Experience Library](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Design_and_User_Experience_Library/GUID-A8DF3EB8-E97C-4DA0-95F6-F464ECC995BC_cover.html)

[Design Principles](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Design_and_UX/designing-for-nokia-devices/nokia-design-principles.html)

[Hildon UI Style Guide](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/eb8a68ba-6225-4d84-ba8f-a00e4a05ff6f/Hildon_2_2_UI_Style_Guide.html)

[Symbian Design Guidelines](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Symbian_Design_Guidelines/)

[Usability & Design Resources](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Usability_&_Design_Resources)

[Ux Resources](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Design/User_experience/)

**Oracle**

[Design Guidelines for Oracle Applications](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/applications/DPG/OBIEE/guidelines/index.html)

[Java Look and Feel Design Guidelines (Sun Microsystems)](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/)

**Samsung**

[Samsung bada Application User Interface Guide](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.appuiguide.help/html/cover_page.htm)

**SonyEricsson**

[User Interface Rulebook (PDF)](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/cws/download/1/716/984/1262667210/DW-102212-UI_Rulebook.pdf)

Comment: Please copy the content from your blog here and don't link to non-English resources without a warning

Comment: Now it is issued correctly? (:

Comment: +1 This is great; exactly what the OP was after, but also a really useful set of links for everyone. If I could favourite-star Answers as well as just Questions this would get a favourite from me.

Comment: And here is twitter's http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ it's also a free kit of HTML, JavaScript and Popular user interface comps

Comment: I disagree, it *is* a great answer, but it is is *not* what OP was after, and *not* what most readers need. It would require reading 25 resources, in order to be sure to get the best one, or the best handful. It is a great answer, because it is has so many resources, but it is only for readers that are already deep into UX, and willing to spend lots of times, maybe a month, exploring new sources.

Comment: Furthermore resources are grouped by sources, not by what they cover, or how they approach/describe/introduce the issues. Not really a helpful way of grouping. (I understand that would have taken lots of time from the answerer).

Answer (score 12):

I also like Alan Cooper's About Face 3: Essentials of Interaction Design as a resource, as well as the quick and dirty [Nielsen Heuristics](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here's perhaps t[he ultimate list of HIGs](http://www.uxbooth.com/resources/a-huge-list-of-style-guides-and-ui-guidelines/) doing the rounds at the moment, which includes various desktop, mobile, and brand guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Another good Alan Cooper book is "[The Inmates are running the Asylum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672316498)" - this is good for understanding *why* so many user experiences suck. If you read it thoughtfully, you'll start thinking about UX in new ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the official [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines for Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx). Also available in pdf format. This is a very detailed guide at almost 900 pages. It has many screen shots from windows 7 with pixel size measurements, grammar etc.